# Returning object from a Java method

Tags: java

I am trying to understand java programming language better. I believe this statement is true:

"In order to return an object from a Java method, you must first declare a variable to hold a reference to the object."

for example:

```
public Ball createRedBall() { 

Ball redBall = new Ball("red"); 
return redBall; 
}
```

So in this case, Ball is a variable that is a reference to the object. Correct?

Comment: `redBall` is a reference to the object created by the `new Ball("red")` statement.

Comment: Ball is actually a class(object specification), redBall is the reference that is returned from method

Comment: No `redBall` is the variable and instance of a `Ball`.

Comment: Is this question really can be asked on SO?

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox - Yes. This question is *valid*. SO doesn't define any kind of *level* for users. The OP has a question, we will try to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to declare variable. Following works:

```
public Ball createRedBall() { 
  return new Ball("red");  
}
```

So yes, you created an objects but didn't create reference variable for it.

Answer (score 1):

Ball is an class and redball is an  object

Answer (score 1):

No. redBall is and object which holds current state of Ball class as an pointer, in java pointers are handled internally by java itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. You can use :

```
private static String someMethod() {
    return new String("hello"); 
 // the object "hello"'s reference is pushed on to the stack. Which is then retrieved by the caller method.
}
```

**So in this case, Ball is a variable that is a reference to the object. Correct?**

No, `Ball` is a *class* and `redBall` is a *reference* to an *instance* of `Ball`

Your code explained:

```
public Ball createRedBall() { 
// an instance level method that returns an Instance (a reference to an instance) of Ball and takes no arguments.
Ball redBall = new Ball("red"); 
// create a new instance of Ball and assign it to the reference redBall.
return redBall; 
//return the redBall reference (and inturn the instance) to the caller method.
// you can just do return new Ball("red"); instead of the above 2 lines of code
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Yes, redBall is a variable to hole the reference to a Ball object.

And no, you don't need the variable to return the object:

```
return new Ball("red");
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to create a variable first to return object from a method.You can directly return the object's. Internally in both the situtation, reference of the object will be passed not the actual object. For Example

```
public Ball createRedBall() { 
Ball redBall = new Ball("red"); 
return redBall; 
}
```

**OR**

```
public Ball createRedBall() { 
return new Ball("red"); 
}
```

Both the method will create an object for Ball in the heap and will only return its reference that is stored in stack.